# error with libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, libraries, shared

When trying to download a Windows XP Virtual Machine from https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads the file I downloaded has an .sfx extension. The file is IE6.WinXP.For.LinuxVirtualBox.sfx. After downloading the file using wget (and by clicking the link through Icedove), I have the file located in my /root directory. Followed the instructions to make it executable then run the file as follows...

```
root@kali:~# chmod +x IE6.WinXP.For.LinuxVirtualBox.sfx
root@kali:~# ./IE6.WinXP.For.LinuxVirtualBox.sfx
./IE6.WinXP.For.LinuxVirtualBox.sfx: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried editing the ld.so.conf file to add /usr/local/lib, I have tried adding /usr/local/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but still get the same error. I have also tried installing libstcdc++.so.6 with apt-get but unable to locate the package. The following results might help...

```
root@kali:~# ldd /root/IE6.WinXP.For.LinuxVirtualBox.sfx
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7759000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7717000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf75b1000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf775a000)
```

This is above my head, please could somebody help me get this VM installed. My system info: 
Linux kali 3.14-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.5-1kali1 (2014-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes symbolic links are broken when you do a system update. Try to search for the version of libstdc++ in your computer with the find command(dont forget to run with sudo) and create a symbolic link with that name(libstdc++.so.6) pointing to your existing library.